# Backbone event callback is called when bound, not triggered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to implement a simple mediator pattern for events, but my event callbacks are being called when I register them with the mediator.

The Mediator is simply:

```
define(function(require){
    'use strict';
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    return _.extend( Backbone.Events);
});
```

I have created a simple View with no backing model or template

```
define(function (require) {

'use strict';

var Backbone = require('backbone');
var mediator = require('mediator');

var Sandbox = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.sandbox',
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents:function(){
        mediator.on("sandbox:change", this.changeText(), this );
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).html("SANDBOX VIEW IS WORKING");
    },

    changeText: function () {
        $(this.el).html("THE TEXT HAS CHANGED");
    }
});

return Sandbox;

});
```

When the view is loaded, the `sandbox:change` event is fired off and the changeText function is called even though nothing has called `mediator.trigger('sandbox:change')`

Why is the callback invoked when it is simply being bound to the mediator object?

Comment: Because your code invokes `this.changeText()` and tells backbone to bind *the result of that invocation*. What you want is `mediator.on("sandbox:change", this.changeText, this )` (notice the absence of `()`).

Comment: Ahh! I see said the blind man... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When the browser evaluates your sandbox change event binding `mediator.on("sandbox:change", this.changeText(), this );` the changeText function is being executed because the `()` are included. What you really want to do is pass the changeText function object to the event binding:

```
    mediator.on("sandbox:change", this.changeText, this );
```

Remember that changeText, is an object that is a member of your view.

```
    var Sandbox = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
        changeText: function () {...}
    });
```

When you want to execute the function, use the parenthesis. When you want to refer to the object, omit the the parenthesis.